# Xamarin.forms Media.Plugin save images

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and Media.Plugin to get some images from the Gallery/Library on iOS/Android.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

It's works well, I managed to display on the application the images but i'd like to make the photo upload persistent, when I change page and come back the photos are still displayed and same if I close the application and restart it.

Later on these images will be uploaded to a server to store it but for now I just need to store it locally to create a demo application.

As the images are displayed in the application I guess they are already stored in a temporary folder so i'd like to get the path of the image and store it into a safe folder to access it even when the application has been closed and reopened.

Do you guys have any solution + examples?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _As the images are displayed in the application I guess they are already stored in a temporary folder_ this is not correct. The displayed images are not temporarily stored in your app folder. You want to same them to App folder once you select them from the gallery

Comment: the MediaFile object returned by the plugin has a Path property.  Use that to permanently copy the image to your app's storage

Comment: Please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702862/xamarin-forms-how-to-hold-image-on-same-page-after-navigating-another-page/37751896#37751896) and let me know if you have any issues. Like @Jason said, you need to copy the image to a permanent location after getting the image data.

Comment: @hvaughan3, your answer on the other question is perfect!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AntoineALEJANDRO Hey no problem, glad it help.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I just have an issue to delete the image, How can I get the image path from the Xamarin.Forms.Image object? image.Source returns an ImageSource object and not a string.

Comment: @AntoineALEJANDRO Unfortunately you will not be able to get the path from an `ImageSource` object. I usually store the path in a separate list or variable. You may want to store the image path in a `Dictionary<string, string>` as `{ "ImageKey1", "/some/image/path/image.png" }`, then add the `"ImageKey1"` to `Image.StyleId` so that you are able to easily look up the path if you can get access to the `Image` instance. You could also simply store the path to the image directly into `Image.StyleId`. If you want to see examples of this, let me know and I will add an answer.

Comment: @hvaughan3 Thanks for the answer. I actually created an image class that inherit `Xamarin.Forms.Image` and added an `imageSource` property so I can access it directly from `image.imageSource`. Thanks a lot for tour help.

Comment: @AntoineALEJANDRO Nice, thats a good idea!